# Get information of uploaded media in .NET

Tags: .net, media

Is it easy to get information about uploaded media (in asp.net).

The format of the media can be flv (video), mp3 (sound) and jpeg, png and gif (images).

I would need resolution (video and images) and duration (video and sound).

Are there .NET api's to get this information or will I have to use third party libraries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar requirement for one of my sites and used [ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/) for that. I think ffmpeg is your best option.

Answer (score 0):

You can also parse the result of [ffprobe](http://www.ffmpeg.org/ffprobe.html)

you can see my post

[How to get video duration in seconds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19013536/how-to-get-video-duration-in-seconds/21405692#21405692)